# Совместимость мышей с линукс

Tags: linux

Очень-очень тупой вопрос, но все же.
Возникла необходимость купить мышь,
но при поиске различных мышей на ozon  увидел что есть поиск по совместимости с операционными системами. Правда ли что у какой либо мыши не может быть дров на линукс?
p.s. все даже самые дешёвые китайские мышки даже сверх старые всегда корректно работали с линукс
ОС: linux mint 20.2 если это важно.

Comment: прошу не бить, линукс юзаю не так давно, в системе не особо разбираюсь.

Comment: если у мышки есть спец кнопки, то они могут не работать. Стандартный кнопки работать будут

Comment: Вся стандартная функциональность мышек работает по стандартному протоколу USB HID, который поддерживается почти абсолютно везде (даже на многих телефонах и телевизорах). Проблемы могут быть только с нестандартной функциональностью, вроде кастомизации нестандартных кнопок или подсветки

Comment: @andreymal А кнопка регулировки dpi работать будет?

Comment: @ArchDemon а кнопка dpi работать будет?

Comment: @Alexalexeev она обычно реализована внутри мышки независимо от компьютера, так что скорее всего будет, но это зависит от конкретной модели мыши

Comment: @Alexalexeev у меня мышь с кнопкой dpi, на linux mint без проблем работает.